# Ruby valid? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been writing test with RSpec.

When I execute `valid?` method, it deletes error message which the object owns.
I couldn't understand why this happens.
Is this RSpec or Ruby specific behaviour? 
If it's the case, how should I get around it?

[image]

And I often see test cases something like,

```
it"isinvalidwithoutafirstname"do
  contact = Contact.new(firstname: nil)
  contact.valid?
  expect(contact.errors[:firstname]).not_to include("can't be blank")
end
```

Why in this example do they uses `contact.valid` before `expect`?

### UPDATE

```
plan = Plan.new(
  xxx_id: xxx_id,
  amount: amount,
  currency: currency,
  interval: interval,
  name: name,
  description: description
)

return plan unless plan.valid?

begin
  XXX::Plan.create(
    id: xxx_id,
    amount: amount,
    currency: currency,
    interval: interval,
    name: name
  )
rescue XXX::XXXError => e
  plan.errors[:base] << e.message
  return plan
end

plan.save && plan
```

This is a part of the method.
I'm new to ruby. Should I put `save` before `return plan` in ruby way?

Answer (score 0):

`contact` won't have an error unless you try to save it.  Just initializing an instance won't give it an error.  The errors object won't be filled until you call `.save` or `.create` on contact.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#valid-questionmark-and-invalid-questionmark

Comment: "until you call .save or .create" - um, _actually_ it is validation process that fills the errors. One can call it directly, using `.valid?`

Answer (score 0):

In your last example you call `Plan.create` without assigning it to any variable. But when exception throws you add errors to variable `plan` which contains valid model object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the value of interval AFTER calling "valid?"? because plan.errors tells you that interval is missing, but it's there when you inspected plan the line before that.

"valid?" clears all errors and then runs validations, so, when you run "valid?", interval is not blank and validations pass, that's the expected behavior, if there are any errors, errors propery gets populated but if there is non, errors will be blank

the spec you posted is perfectly fine, you have an object in an invalid state (first name is nil) so valid? adds an error on that field (would be good to also test "expect(contact).to be_invalid")